# $this->find not working in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a model with the name Deal `class Deal extends AppModel`

Now in my controller I call a method in the Deal model called getDeal()

$dealInfo = Deal::getDeal($dealID);

I want the info returned to me but the var_dump displays blank

```
function getDeal($dealID){

    $deal = $this->Deal->find('first', array(
                            'conditions' => 
                                'Deal.id' =>$dealID

                            ) ,
                            'fields' => array(
                                'Deal.id'
                            ) ,

                            'recursive' => 1,

                            ));
}
```

This is the first time I'm working in cakePHP, so this question might sound a bit dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your function declaration, `$deal_id` does not exist and as you can see from the parameter you pass to the function which should me `$deal_id` and not `dealID`. So you have a misdeclared function calling find with a variable that does not exist.

Comment: I'm calling this in the Deal model, so it should look like this $this->Deal->find

Comment: That was a typo in the question, still with that being correct, still nothing happens

Comment: 'fields' should be declared as 'fields' => array('Deal.id')

Comment: Still for some odd reason nothing, I totally removed fields and alsoe tried it with an array and still nothing

Comment: Can you please update your post to see what you currently have? Do you have debug set to 2 to see what the error is ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3072/discussion-between-8vius-and-roland)

Answer (score 2):

When you're just using an id as your find condition you can use CakePHP's dynamic finder methods.

Dynamic finders work like this.

```
$this->Model->findByModelFieldName();
```

In your example it would be

```
$this->findById($dealId, array(
    'fields' => array('Deal.id'),
    'recursive' => 1
));
```

Comment: Fantastic, I'll make a note, this could be useful

Comment: Whoops, messed up my example. Updating it now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm just being mental, but is this simply because you're not returning anything from `getDeal()`?

Try adding `return $deal;` and see if that helps. Your question doesn't state exactly where you're doing the `var_dump` so I might be well off.

**Edit:**

As per the discussion with you and 8vius, we've established that this isn't right, and you simply need to change `$this->Deal->find()` to `$this->find()` because its being run from the model.

Comment: The root cause was that I did not include Deal to the $uses at the top of the controller